# golangci-lint constant explicit type

Tags: go

I have a question about golangci-lint.
The linter returns me for something like:

```
type outputFormat string

const (
    formatNone outputFormat = ""
    formatText              = "TEXT"
    formatJSON              = "JSON"
)
```

an error like:

> only the first constant in this group has an explicit type
>   (staticcheck)
>   formatNone outputFormat = ""

But what's the problem about it?
In https://go101.org/article/constants-and-variables.html they describe in chapter **Autocomplete in constant declarations** that incomplete constants will be recognized and filled.

I did not find any reference which tells me to avoid using incomplete constant definitions.

Can somebody explain to me, what's the matter behind that?

Comment: Note, this is not about golangci-lint, it's about [staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io/).

Comment: *"In a group-style constant declaration, except the first constant specification, other constant specifications can be incomplete. An incomplete constant specification **doesn't contain the = symbol**.*" Yours, however, does, so formatText and formatJSON will not have the type you expect them to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As explained in [staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io/)'s [documentation for that check](https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#SA9004):

> In a constant declaration such as the following:
>
> ```
> const (
>      First byte = 1
>      Second     = 2
> )
> ```
>
> the constant `Second` does **not** have the same type as the constant `First`. This construct shouldn't be confused with
>
> ```
> const (
>       First byte = iota
>       Second
> )
> ```
>
> where `First` and `Second` do indeed have the same type. The type is only passed on when no explicit value is assigned to the constant.
>
> When declaring enumerations with explicit values it is therefore important not to write
>
> ```
> const (
>       EnumFirst EnumType = 1
>       EnumSecond         = 2
>       EnumThird          = 3
> )
> ```
>
> This discrepancy in types can cause various confusing behaviors and bugs.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved the issue by including the type for all the enum items

```
type Verb string

const (
    DEL  Verb = "DEL"
    POST Verb = "POST"
    GET  Verb = "GET"
)
```

when I was puttig Verb only on the first enum (DEL) I got your same issue